# I'm looking to resolve my " Microsoft jscript complilation error" when creating a vue project

Tags: vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNmpH.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bknpg.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEgME.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNOa7.jpg)

Hi Guys, I'm getting Microsoft jscript complilation error when i'm creating a vue project. I have already installed vue and cli using npm commands. I have attached a screenshot of error for the reference, need your suggestions guys?

Comment: the error code looks like a `syntax error`. try and create a folder without a `.` only plain text and try it again. do you got node.js installed by the way?

Comment: thanks for your answer wittgenstein, yes i have a node.js version v12.18.3 installed in my machine. Tried removing . in the folder, however, i'm still getting the same error even after installing vue, vue-cli again.  Also, tried creating a project in terminal by running vue ui command, getting error there too. I have attached error screenshot in the main post to refer. Is there something i'm missing already. I'm actually creating a Vue folder inside my E drive and then installing vue and cli on it and trying to create a vue project. Can this be done or please suggest me some better way. :)

Comment: how does your folder is named? have you tried plain text like `vue` or `project`?

Comment: yes, I have named the folder as Vue in E drive changing it from Vue.js, should all be in small case here in folder name? have attached the newer screenshots in the main post though, please check and advice, where is the miss here.

Comment: I'm now using the path as "E:\project>vue create movieapp" and changed my folder name as "project" inplace of "Vue",  still i'm getting the same compliation error. Updated screenshot attached in the main post. Please check and advice. TIA :)